# Proof verification in constructive analysis

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I want to proof something in constructive analysis, that means without the law of excluded middle (or, if one prefers this interpretation, in intuitionistic logic).

First some definitions:

$C(x_1,x_2) = \{ \sum_{i=1}^{2} \lambda_i x_i : \lambda_i \in [0,1]\wedge \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1 \}$.

A metric is the same as in "standard" analysis.

For some subset $Y$ of a metric space $X$ we define the distance from $x \in X$ to $Y$ by $d(x,Y) = \inf \{d(x,y) : y \in Y \}$.

Now the problem: I have a real number $\neg(x=0)$ and define the vectors $x_1 = (1,x)$ and $x_2 = (x,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  I want to show that $\neg(0= d(0,C(x_1,x_2))$.

To this end I want to use the following rule: If under the hypothesis of $b$ the statements $a$ and $\neg a$ both lead to $\bot$, then I get $\neg b$ (this does hold in intuitionistic logic). So I assume $0= d(0,C(x_1,x_2) = \inf \{d(0,\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 : \lambda \in [0,1] \} $. Let $\lambda_n$ be a sequence such that in the limit we attain the infimum above. Then I have two cases: i) $\lambda_n \rightarrow 0$ or ii) $\lambda_n \rightarrow t \in (0,1]$. In the first case is get $0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}d(0,\lambda_n x_1 + (1-\lambda_n) x_2) = d(0, x_2) $ and thus $x_2 = 0$, hence $x = 0$; a contradiction. In the latter case I get $0 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}d(0,\lambda_n x_1 + (1-\lambda_n) x_2) = d(0,t x_1 + (1-t) x_2 )= d(0,t(1,x) + t(x,0))$. In particular $tx = 0$, a contradiction. In total I get the desired result.

Inter alia I have the following questions: Can I define such a sequence $\lambda_n$?. Can i conclude constructively from $tx= 0$ that either $t = 0$ or $x =0$?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer: my proof has some flaws, in particular such a sequence can not be defined constructively. However, I did come up with the following proof:

Assume
            \begin{align}\label{eq11}
    0=d(0,C(a_1,a_2)).
    \end{align} We call this equation * .
            Notice that $d(0,C(a_1,a_2)) = \inf \{d(0,\lambda a_1 + (1-\lambda)a_2) : \lambda \in [0,1]\}$. 
            We are going to show that (*) implies $x=0$, which would contradict $\neg(x=0)$. Assume that $\vert x \vert > 0$. We have two cases:

Case 1 $(x > 0)$: we have either $\lambda > 1/2$ or $ \lambda < 2/3$. In the first case we obtain $ \lambda + (1-\lambda)x > 1/2 > 0$ and in the latter case $\lambda + (1-\lambda) x > x/3  > 0$. Therefore both contradict (*).

Case 2 $(x < 0)$:  we may assume $\vert x \vert < 1/2$. We have either $\lambda > -x /3$ or $\lambda < -x/2$. In the first case we get $\lambda x < - x^2/3 < 0$. In the latter case we obtain $ \lambda + (1-\lambda)x < \lambda +x/2  < 0$. Therefore both contradict (*).

In total we observe $x =0$. Thus $(*)$ implies $\bot$, i.e. we get $\neg(0=d(0,C(a_1,a_2))$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer the following problem: $xy = 0$ then either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. First some definitions:

A real number is a subset x of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ such that

i) for all $(q,q')$ in $x$ we have $ q \le q'$,

ii) for all $(q,q')$ and $(r,r')$ in $x$, the closed intervals $[q,q']$ and $[r,r']$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ intersect in points in $\mathbb{Q}$,

iii)  for all positive rational $\varepsilon$ there exits $(q,q')$ in $x$ such that $ q' - q < \varepsilon$.

We say that two real numbers $x$ and $y$ are 
equal if for all $(q,q') \in x $ and all $(r,r') \in y$ the closed intervals  $[q,q']$ and $[r,r']$ have a rational point in common.

The product  $xy$ is defined to be the set of all rational pairs $(s,s')$ such that there exists $ (q,q') \in x$ and $(r,r') \in y$ with
\begin{align*}
s = \min\left\{qr,qr',q'r,q'r'\right\}, \quad s' = \max\left\{qr,qr',q'r,q'r'\right\}.
\end{align*}

Now to the problem: First notice that case distinction is allowed when considering rational numbers.

Let $(q,q') \in x$ and $(r,r') \in y$. Choose $(0,0) \in 0$. Set $s = \min\left\{qr,qr',q'r,q'r'\right\}$ and $s' = \max\left\{qr,qr',q'r,q'r'\right\}$. 
Let $(u,u') \in 0$. By definition we get $ u \le 0 \le u'$ and thus $0 \in [u,u']$. It now suffices to show $0 \in [q,q']$ or $0 \in [r,r']$. Notice first that we are not going to consider cases where $q > q'$ or $r > r'$, since this is not possible due to the definition. By assumption we have $ 0 \in [s,s']$.

Case 1(there exists an element $a \in \left\{qr,qr',q'r,q'r'\right\}$ such that $a = 0$): w.l.o.g assume $a = qr$. By this we get either $q = 0$ or $r = 0$. In the first case we get $ 0 \in [q,q']$ and in the latter we get $ 0 \in [r,r']$.

Case 2(there exist elements $a,b \in \left\{qr,qr',q'r,q'r'\right\}$ such that $a < 0 < b$).

Case 2.1($a = qr$ and $b = q'r$): by this we get $q < 0$ and $r > 0$. Therefore  $q' > 0$ and thus $0 \in [q,q']$.

Case 2.2($a = qr$ and $b = q'r'$).

Case 2.2.1($q < 0$ and $r > 0$): then we get $r' > 0$ and thus $ 0 \in [r,r']$.

Case 2.2.2($q > 0$ and $r < 0$): then we get $q' > 0$ and thus $ 0 \in [q,q']$.

Case 2.3($a = q'r$ and $b = qr'$): this implies $q' > 0$ and $r < 0$.

Case 2.3.1($q >0$ and $r '> 0$): then we get $ 0 \in [r,r']$.

Case 2.3.2($q < 0$ and $r ' < 0$): then we get  $ 0 \in [q,q']$.

Comment: This only shows that $0 \in [r,r'] \cup [q,q']$ for every $(r,r') \in y$ and $(q, q') \in x$ which is demonstrably different from saying that either $0 \in [r,r']$ for every $(r,r') \in y$  or else $0 \in [q,q']$ for every  $(q, q') \in x$. Unfortunately universal quantification doesn't work with disjunction like it does with conjunction. So while we can say whether $r=0$ or $q=0$ whenever $rq=0$, the argument you gave ultimately doesn't prove what you want it to prove.

Answer (score 0):

I need to read your post more carefully which I shall do tomorrow.
Are you reading about constructive analysis from a certain textbook?

I do know that the statement $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R \left(xy = 0 \implies \left(x=0 \lor y=0\right)\right)$ is equivalent to the lesser limited principle of omniscience (LLPO) which is known be nonconstructive (but weaker than LEM). I will prove the relevant (forward) direction of this aforementioned equivalence tomorrow.

---

**Lesser limited principle of omniscience** (LLPO): For each binary sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with at most one term equal to $1$, either $a_{2n-1}=0$ for all $n$ or else $a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$.

---

Suppose that the statement $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R \left(xy = 0 \implies \left(x=0 \lor y=0\right)\right)$ holds. Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a binary sequence with at most one term equal to $1$. We define two sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ by
\begin{equation}x_n:= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{k} & \text{ if } \, 2k-1 \leq n \text{ and } \, a_{2k-1}=1, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}y_n:= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{k} & \text{ if } \, 2k \leq n \text{ and } \, a_{2k}=1, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Put $x=\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ and $y=\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$. Notice $xy=0$, since $x_ny_n = 0$  for every $n \in \mathbb N$. Furthermore, $x=0$ iff $a_{2n-1}=0$ for all $n$, and $y=0$ iff $a_{2n}=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: The book I am working with is Techniques of Constructive Analysis by Douglas Bridges and Luminiţa  Simona Vîţă.

Comment: @Diamir I got the impression. Do you own a full copy? Is there anything you are interested in besides the proof that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R \left(xy = 0 \implies \left(x=0 \lor y=0\right)\right)$ implies LLPO?

Comment: Yes, I am interested if my proof was correct. However, I did realise that it is not and I made another one myself. And why is my proof of $xy = 0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$ incorrect? (it has to be, since otherwise that would provide a constructive proof of LLPO).

Comment: Can you spot the mistake in my proof? To me everything seems fine so I am a bit confused.

Comment: Notice case 1 is LLPO, as it relies on the ability to make the same determination that the argument above shows cannot be made constructively.

Comment: The numbers $x$ and $y$ are a Brouwerian example of two real numbers such that $xy=0$ for which we cannot decide whether $x=0$ or $y=0$. Notice that $x$ and $y$ are both defined to be the limits of sequences of rational numbers.

Comment: But case 1 only involves rational numbers. And for the rational numbers LLPO holds (even LPO does). 
I don't get what you mean with your second post, sorry. And real numbers are (in my case) not defined as limits of rational numbers. They are defined to be rational pairs with certain properties (listed in my answer below).

Comment: Well $x$ and $y$ are both rational numbers. I own the same book you are using and I only recall the authors mentioning in the first chapter that the axiom of choice holds for so-called basic sets such as $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$. I have yet to encounter any such concession being given to sets of rational numbers. What about the rational $x$ used in the proof of proposition 2.1.13?

Comment: i) I don't see why $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers. ii) I don't see why the axiom of choice is relevant here. I only use LPO (which does hold for rational numbers). iii) In my copy of the book they use a real number $x$ in the prop you are referring to.

Comment: Prop 2.1.13: https://imgur.com/RBuLdAG. So either $x$ equals $0$ or else $x=(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$ for some positive integer $n$. In what scenario could $x$ fail to be rational? The rational numbers are a subset of the real numbers, and so it is perfectly fair to merely characterize $x$ as being real.

Comment: And we could use the same number $x$ defined in proposition 2.1.13 to show that the statement $\forall x \in \mathbb R ( x=0 \lor x>0 \lor x<0)$ implies LPO. By the way, LPO implies LLPO.

Comment: Since inequality on the rationals is defined to be the denial inequality, in some sense you are not entirely incorrect. Notice how we could have $q=0$ and $r=0$ but from this we can't say whether $0 \in [q,q′]$ for all $(q,q′)\in x$ or $0 \in [r,r′]$ for all $(r,r′) \in y$. Basically, you have shown $\forall (q,q') \in x \; \forall (r, r') \in y \left( 0 \in [q,q'] \lor 0 \in [r,r'] \right)$ but you want to show $\forall (q,q') \in x \left( 0 \in [q,q'] \right) \lor \forall (r,r') \in y \left( 0 \in [r,r'] \right)$. These two statements mean demonstrably different things.

Comment: So while we can say whether $r=0$ or $q=0$ whenever $rq=0$, the argument you gave ultimately doesn't prove what you intend it to prove. Sorry for any confusion a previous comment of mine may have caused, hopefully the preceding comment clarifies things.

Comment: Perhaps it would be somewhat insightful if I defined the two real numbers by $x= \left\{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right) : \forall k \leq n \; (a_{2k-1}=0) \right\} \cup \left\{\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right):a_{2n-1}=1\right\}$ and $y= \left\{\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right) : \forall k \leq n \; (a_{2k}=0) \right\} \cup \left\{\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right):a_{2n}=1\right\}$.